# Copyright of microscopy data acquired by myself

Tags: copyright

The question is the following: What is the copyright of imaging data (microscopy) I acquired during working in a research laboratory? Can I use this on my homepage / personal website?

I took the images with a microscope on my own. So is this my data?

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question without knowing what contracts you're under and your jurisdiction. It's also a legal question that can't be definitively answered for you except for by a lawyer.

Comment: I recorded the data during my master's thesis. Probably should consult my old advisor.

Comment: Duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11359/can-you-copyright-data

Answer (score 1):

Copyright law varies over the world, but in many places data itself can't be copyrighted, but interpretations of it can be.

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright): "Copyright may apply to a wide range of creative, intellectual, or artistic forms, or "works"."

Your best action is to contact the source and ask them. It may be that what you have is "data" or it may be something else to which copyright does apply.

And copyright doesn't necessarily mean "no use whatever". There are permitted actions also.

Comment: Photos certainly have copyright associated with them, explicitly or implicitly. But there are many details to the issue here that would need to be looked at in context of the country and working arrangement. Likely, just asking if the image can be posted on your homepage will generate a 'yes, of course' answer...

Comment: @JonCuster, yes, that is certainly true of photographs, but do such microscope images qualify as creative works or as data? It seems to be an edge case. IANAL.

Comment: there are contests of the best artistic images from microscopes, so certainly for those. Good microscopists aren't just snapping images but using their skill and judgement to get a picture that reveals the result in the best way possible - there is lots of creative work (but I'm biased, mostly because I was never a good microscopist and was always amazed at those who were).

Comment: If it's not plain data, there's probably a hierarchy of claims to it under copyright starting with whoever composed the image and pressed the shutter release and working up the chain of command to the top of the university and maybe the funding agency. All depend on local, regional, and national laws and arrangements. Where is @stephanmg located? How was the work funded? Who is their employer? In some nations it may matter who funded or owns the microscope.

Comment: Interesting comments, I will try to refine my question to make it answerable, if not feel free to flag it.

Comment: @JonCuster Is not correct.  Photos are only protected by copyright if they are creative works.  If they are data which is not a creative work then they are not protected.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - again, it would take a court decision on artistic intent. The microscopists I know are indeed artists, working hard to get the best rendition to reveal what is there clearly. They aren't just snapping photos.

Comment: @JonCuster I agree.